# What am I doing wrong in this implementation of an NMRU?

Tags: c++, caching

I am trying to implement an NMRU in this code, I believe I am 80% of the way there I just need some help figuring out what else to implement. I know that the random way value should be between 0 and assoc, and I need to verify that the value's _repl != 0. The for loop in my code is obsolete the way I have it right now, and I am a little unsure how to fix it.

```
//use rand function to choose smallest value that IS NOT 0
//near (NMRU)
int Replace(SET_t* tar, LARGEINT tag, int assoc) {
    srand(time(NULL)); //initialization
    int lruWay = rand() % assoc; //returns a random integer between 0 and RAND_MAX
    for (int way != 0; way < assoc; way++)
    if (tar->_repl[way] != 0 ){ //dont know if I need this
        break; //break loop
    }
    return lruWay;
```

Comment: is this the real code? `for (int way != 0; ` is a typo

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should be invoked once at beginning of main. Calling it here will lead to strange not random results.

Comment: Also loop does nothing (has not visible effects), so compiler will remove it.